# How do I add sub items to the main menu, and how do I put it on the side of the page?

Tags: node.js, vcl.js

1. How do you add a navigation menu bar which is positioned on the left side of the home page of a Vcl.js application?
2. How do you create sub menu items to the top menu navigation bar on the home page?

I am looking at the sample Customer Center example that was provided for the vcl.js framework.

Comment: Nice questions, but remember that this is not a forum. You need to ask one specific question, that can have one specific answer. Your questions are now a bit too open. Show us what you've tried, and where you got stuck, so we can help out with specific advice to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

menu handling is done on main.ts at the application level

```
var item = V.Application.addNavbarItem("HOME2", "icon-home icon-white", () => {
      V.Application.navigateToPage("PageHome2", []); //this is the default click event
});
var subitem = b.addMenuItem('submenu');
subitem.onClicked = () => {
    //on click
}
```